# Automatically insert fold tags around visually selected text in vim

Tags: vim

I have started to use `set foldmethod=marker`, because I find it more convenient to use rather than `syntax`.

But it has the disadvantage of needing to write `// {{{ my title` and  `// }}}` around any folding code candidate.

It would be nice if I could select a part of code in visual mode, and call a command ( or some commands) that would insert the two markers before and after the selected code.

Are there any way to do that in vim ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. Visually select the block then input the command `:fold`

It automatically writes the two tags `/*{{{*/` and `/*}}}*/`.

Answer (score 1):

When in visual mode, with the text to be folded highlighted, press `zf`. This is better than using `:fold` as you don't have to escape to the command prompt (and use less keystrokes).